# Landscape LDS - Remove Computer(s)

Tags: server, landscape

I have an installation of Landscape LDS 15.11 on 14.04 and have a couple of computers that I would like to remove. I have tried 'Remove computer' from within the computer properties but nothing happens. I have also removed the license and then tried to 'Remove computer' and same result.

Has anyone else experienced this issue or have a workaround for it?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that I had an issue with RabbitMQ. The landscape-appserver was unable to authenticate to RabbitMQ. Once I resolved this, I was able to remove the machines without issue.

Comment: would be nice to hear a little more about how you did this.

Answer (score 0):

According to Landscape docs, you should do these tasks:

1. Remove the landscape-client package from the registered machine (did you do this? you didn't mention in your question.)
2. In Landscape, select the machine(s) you want to remove and click on "Info", so that you get to the info page
3. There, just below the comment box, is a link called "Remove this computer...". Click on it and confirm the action

Comment: Yes - I removed the client from the machine that I want to remove from landscape:

sudo apt-get remove landscape-client landscape-common

The machines are still in Landscape. I have also tried to remove them from the web interface and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

From what I found :

```
cd /var/log/rabbitmq/
tail -f rabbit@landscape.log (or different name perhaps on your server)
```

Check the error message:

```
*=ERROR REPORT==== 11-May-2018::12:04:32 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.2798.0> (127.0.0.1:53570 -> 127.0.0.1:5672):
{handshake_error,starting,0,
                 {amqp_error,access_refused,
                             "AMQPLAIN login refused: user 'landscape' - invalid credentials",
                             'connection.start_ok'}}*
```

If this is the problem follow these instructions:

```
less /opt/canonical/landscape/configs/standalone/service.conf
```

Check section `[broker]`

Copy the password string part after the `b64:`

Use base64 decoder ([here's an online one](https://www.base64decode.org/)) or you can use

```
base64 -d <<< "paste the coded string here"
```

Execute the command

```
rabbitmqctl change_password <user> <password>
```

Check `rabbitmq` logfile again and check if computer is removed

Hope this helps!